# How to get friends from XMPPRoster?

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I try like this:

```
XMPPRosterMemoryStorage *xmppRosterMemStorage = [[XMPPRosterMemoryStorage alloc] init];
XMPPRoster *xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:xmppRosterMemStorage
                                         dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoster addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
xmppRoster.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = true;
xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = true;
[xmppRoster activate:xmppStream];
[xmppRoster fetchRoster];
```

But **`xmppRoster`** is empty. Why?

Comment: I also use xmppRosterDidPopulate. But this method sent once after lunch app. In comments write: Notification that the roster has received the roster from the server.
If parent.autoFetchRoster is YES, the roster will automatically be fetched once the user authenticates. But this not happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roster items are stored in `[xmppRosterMemStorage mainThreadManagedObjectContext]`, you can use it with `NSFetchedResultsController` as datasource for your `UITableView`, see iPhoneXMPP example in the XMPPFramework sources

Comment: Can I fetch Roster items automatically? For example if any user deleted or add from/to roster sent any function

Comment: When you send `xmppRoster activate:xmppStream` - roster items are **automatically** fetched, stored in `xmppRosterMemStorage` and `xmppRoster` **automatically** track changes (additions or deletions) for you.

Comment: I try make like you say - use NSFetchedResultsController, but nothing. Now I can add user in roster, deleted, accept friendship request. I want understand how detect if user go to Offline, Online, deleted, add and view new list roster in UITableViewController. Sorry foe my English. You can give me simple working code?

Comment: Just open iPhoneXMPP example from XMPPFramework - and you will see this in action - UITableViewController with NSFetchedResultsController, which shows you sections "Online", "Away", "Offline", etc., and it will correctly updates when your contacts change their status.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very match. I try make all how in iPhonwXMPP. In method fetchedResultController variable mod == nil. This is happened because method [xmppRosterStorage mainThread...] commented. Why? What me do?

Comment: `mainThreadManagedObjectContext` is inherited from `XMPPCoreDataStorage`, so when you proper initialized `XMPPRoster` with instance of `XMPPRosterMemoryStorage` or `XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage` - all should work ok. Have you tried to run iPhoneXMPP example as is?

Comment: I have database on server. It storage user's data like name, last name, photo, status etc. Now I fetch XMPPUserCoreDataSorage, who contains jid. I want fetch user's data from my database about each user in my Roster. But I do not want make request every time when buddy go to Offline or deleted. How make this?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use `NSFetchedResultsController`, you can get the JIDs of your roster from calling `jidsForXMPPStream` on the roster storage object.

Here's how I have used it -

```
- (void)xmppRosterDidEndPopulating:(XMPPRoster *)sender{
    [appDelegate.mContactHandler clearContacts];
    NSArray* jids = [mXmppRosterStorage jidsForXMPPStream:self.xmppStream];
    for (int i=0; i<jids.count; i++)
    {
        RosterContact* contact = [[RosterContact alloc]init];
        contact.jid = [jids objectAtIndex:i];
        [appDelegate.mContactHandler addContact:contact];
    }
    [self postResultNotification:kReload withResult:nil];
}
```

I have used XMPPRoster's delegate method to know when the roster have finished loading. I then extract the jid from the storage and create my own `RosterContact` object which is just a custom class I have created to store contact data. I then post a notification to reload the tableview where I am showing the contact list.

Here's my roster declaration -

```
mXmppRosterStorage = [[XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage alloc] init];

mXmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:mXmppRosterStorage];

mXmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = YES;
mXmppRoster.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = YES;
```

I hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for swift.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50151198/2781720

```
func getList() {
  let query = try! XMLElement(xmlString: "<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items' node='all users'/>")
  let iq = XMPPIQ(type: "get", to: XMPPJID(string: "Your Host Name"), elementID: xmppStream.generateUUID(), child: query)
  iq?.addAttribute(withName: "id", stringValue: "get")
  xmppStream.send(iq)
}

extension YourClassName: XMPPRosterDelegate {

   func xmppRosterDidEndPopulating(_ sender: XMPPRoster!) {
     if let jids = xmppRoster.xmppRosterStorage.jids(for: xmppStream) as? [XMPPJID] {
       print("JIDS: \(String(describing: jids))")
       for item in jids {
         print(item.user)
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Hope this helps!