# Get Friends list from openfire Server

Tags: xmpp, chat, objective-c-blocks, openfire

How to get all friends programmatically from openfire server in objective C, I am using `XMPP` Framework for chat Functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function to fetch friends.

Add your host name in below function.

```
func getList() {
  let query = try! XMLElement(xmlString: "<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items' node='all users'/>")
  let iq = XMPPIQ(type: "get", to: XMPPJID(string: "Your Host Name"), elementID: xmppStream.generateUUID(), child: query)
  iq?.addAttribute(withName: "id", stringValue: "get")
  xmppStream.send(iq)
}
```

You will get the list in delegate method.

```
extension YourClassName: XMPPRosterDelegate {

    func xmppRosterDidEndPopulating(_ sender: XMPPRoster!) {
        if let jids = xmppRoster.xmppRosterStorage.jids(for: xmppStream) as? [XMPPJID] {
            print("JIDS: \(String(describing: jids))")
            for item in jids {
                print(item.user)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can have a look at my this link for XMPP Connection and different delegates.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50149977/2781720

Answer (score 0):

In iOS you can easily get Group members/friends using below function in xmpp

```
- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchModeratorsList:(NSArray *)items
```